# Join two hive tables and search for a string

Tags: hive

I am new to hive and I have two tables which contains access logs created like this.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE rwloglines(line string) STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'hdfs:///rwlogs'
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dpxloglines(line string) STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'hdfs:///dpxlogs'
```

both of these will contain a Id which is made of 20 characters [A-Z][0-9]. I want to join these two tables and search for the Id. What is the query I should write in hive

Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to spilt the contents of each file into various columns like id , ip adde, error msg etc. And then load it to hive table specifying these columns in its schema.

Then

```
  select id from rwloglines a join dpxloglines b where id='';
```